# VC++/.net exe does not run on Remote Desktop. (WinMM.dll & rdpsnd.dll causing the problem)

Tags: visual-c++, .net-3.5

I have one VC++ project(exe), which depends on several `.dlls` and these `.dll` are developed in different languages & versions i.e. - `C#`.
Building the project On **.Net framework version v1.1.4322**, it gets executed locally as well as from Remote Desktop.
But when I used **.Net Framework version v2.0.50727** & build my application, its working on my local machine but not getting execute via remote desktop.

I used **"Dependency Walker"** to know what happening at the time of invoking application.
It shows after `RDPSND.DLL` called from `WINMM.dll`, it starts detaching and unregistered the application.

Is there any way to figure out the root-cause & fix the issue?
I have attached the log.

```
LoadLibraryW("rdpsnd.dll") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43384.
Loaded "RDPSND.DLL" at address 0x5DAC0000.  Successfully hooked module.
Loaded "WINSTA.DLL" at address 0x76360000.  Successfully hooked module.
LoadLibraryW("rdpsnd.dll") returned 0x5DAC0000.
DllMain(0x76360000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "WINSTA.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x76360000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "WINSTA.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x5DAC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "RDPSND.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x5DAC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "RDPSND.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
GetProcAddress(0x5DAC0000 [RDPSND.DLL], "DriverProc") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43034 and returned 0x5DAC13AD.
GetProcAddress(0x5DAC0000 [RDPSND.DLL], "wodMessage") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43AFA and returned 0x5DAC142B.
LoadLibraryW("rdpsnd.dll") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43384.
LoadLibraryW("rdpsnd.dll") returned 0x5DAC0000.
GetProcAddress(0x5DAC0000 [RDPSND.DLL], "DriverProc") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43034 and returned 0x5DAC13AD.
GetProcAddress(0x5DAC0000 [RDPSND.DLL], "widMessage") called from "WINMM.DLL" at address 0x76B43AFA and returned 0x5DAC1410.
DllMain(0x71AB0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "WS2_32.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x71AB0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "WS2_32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x71AA0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "WS2HELP.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x71AA0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "WS2HELP.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x76C90000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "IMAGEHLP.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x76C90000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "IMAGEHLP.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x10000000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "DOCKEXT4DLL_NU.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x10000000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "DOCKEXT4DLL_NU.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x789E0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "MFC90U.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x789E0000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "MFC90U.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x77F60000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "SHLWAPI.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x77F60000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "SHLWAPI.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
DllMain(0x78520000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCR90.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x78520000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x00000000) in "MSVCR90.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
Unloaded "DBCLIENTUTILITY_NU.DLL" at address 0x04E20000.
Unloaded "NARECDLL_NU.DLL" at address 0x08380000.
Unloaded "MPGPDFDLL_NU.DLL" at address 0x041F0000.
Unloaded "P_OBJS_NEWOBJECTSTREAMER_NU.DLL" at address
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the workaround for this issue. This issue is due to MSCOREE.dll.

Refer the link:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/329819/freelibrary-in-the-winmm-dlls-module-initialization-routine-causes-access-violation

Thanks,
Suraj